# Altium: How can I dim the layers I'm not currently using?

Tags: altium, dimming, layers

The routes on all layers are fully bright. I want to dim the ones on the layers not currently used.

I don't mean dimming ALL routes (even on the layer I'm currently on) except the one segment I'm selecting.

Comment: Ctrl left-click on the one Route your are currently working with, and it will be highlighted. Though it will highlight only one route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shift-S will dim all but the current layer (Single Layer Mode). Repeat to get back. One of the most useful keyboard shortcuts in the PCB editor.

Comment: it worked, but it masks all other layers instead of dimming it

Comment: You can select the available Single layer display modes in Preferences->Board Insight Display but I think the dimmed/monochromed/hidden layers are always going to be masked against selection.